# English with Australian citizenship travel

Tags: visas, australia, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, passport-renewals

I am English with Australian citizenship by descent. I'm off to Australia in October 2018. I've been trying hard to find from the embassy if I can travel on an English passport with a tourist visa. My Australian passport expired over 10 years ago and I got married since, so I think I would have to reapply as a lot of time has passed and my name changed. Is it worth trying to apply for the visa and see if they let me do it?

I would be most grateful for any help.

Elizabeth

Comment: `English passport with a tourist visa` Who told you you need a visa ? UK citizens don't need one. You only need an ETA and that is processed for free.

Answer (score 8):

> As an Australian citizen you must always leave and enter Australia on an Australian passport. If you also have a passport from another country you can use that for travel once you have left Australia.
>
> People trying to enter Australia as an Australian citizen but without an Australian passport face difficulties and delays. The Australian Passport Office provides more information.

[Source](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/citi/Curr/Citizenship-through-travel)

So no, you need to apply for and get a new Australian passport before you travel to Australia or you might be stopped by the airline or face a long immigration interview till they can verify your citizenship. You are not entitled to an Australian visa since you are an Australian citizen.

Comment: Thank you I had an idea that I would but was hoping to save some money.  Off to get an application form